# Issue with browser buttons in Laravel Ajax pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-pagination

when I go from the paginate(list page) page to the details page and after some time when I return to the previous page using the browser back button then break the actual design in Laravel Ajax pagination.

**Here is my code**

**backend/pages/folder/list blade view**

```
@extends('backend.layouts.default')
@section('content')
   <div class="panel panel-flat mbl-panel-list">
     a design section is here
     //Datatable start
     @if ($ComList->isEmpty())
            <div class="row">
              a design here
            </div>
        @else
            @include('backend/pages/journal/journalTable')
        @endif
   </div>
@stop
```

```
laravel return 
-----------------
if ($request->ajax()) {
     return view('backend/pages/folder/folderTable', compact($data))->render();
}else{
     return view('backend/pages/folder/list', compact($data));
 }
jquery ajax:
---------------

$('body').on('click', '.custom_pagination .pagination a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');//http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/folder/list?page=4
    getArticles(url)
        window.history.pushState("", "", url);
    });

    function getArticles(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url : url ,
            method:'GET',
        })
    .done(function (data) {
            $(TableParentClass).html(data);         
        })
        
        .fail(function (error) {
            alert('Sorry, Your pagination could not be loaded.');
        });
    }
```

I want the actual design when i change the route paginate page to another page and return back previous spage by browser back button.

like theis image.
[actual design](https://ibb.co/K9SVwQm)

when i click edit button and change the url then design is here.
[route change from paginate page](https://ibb.co/rGcj37W)

back button click then design break.
[break design](https://ibb.co/9vFbyHQ)

Comment: what is `$data`?

Comment: @krisgjika $data=[
                'folderStatus', 
                'folderOrder', 
                'folderCount', 
                'passengerType',
                'folderSeach',
                'clientList',
            ];

Comment: this is likely bc you have merged two routes into one. Check when you press the back button does your route return the `backend/pages/folder/folderTable` view or what you would expect the `backend/pages/folder/list` view.

Comment: Hello @krisgjika,
 Thank you for taking the time to assist me with my previous question. I have updated my question and would greatly appreciate it if you could take another look and provide further guidance. Thank you for your kind assistance.